# cp command won't run if executed from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

i have very simple shell script

```sh
#!/bin/bash    
cp -rf /var/www/ksite/app2/* /var/www/ksite/app
echo "----"
echo "done"
```

but seems cp command fails

if i execute

```sh
cp -rf /var/www/ksite/app2/* /var/www/ksite/app
```

from terminal everything work ok. Can someone tell me how to include cp in shell script?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors in script? Why you are thinking `cp` fails?

Comment: *cp command fails* in what way?  What is the error message?  Most likely it is a $PATH problem.

Comment: Did you make the shell script an eXecutable file?

Comment: Just covering all the bases .. do the permissions vary between the excutions .. i.e. do you execute one with sudo/root privileges, the other as user (unlikely, but thought I'd ask since we *don't* know what the exact error is)

Comment: @cdarke Not sure how the $PATH could be involved here  .. certainly `cp` is on the path, no?

Comment: @levon: no, there is no certainty, someone could have set path and wiped it, e.g. `PATH=/home/user1/bin` (real example).  We must see the error message.

Comment: @cdarke Ugh .. well I guess (that would be pretty bad). Definitely agreed on needing to see more information on the error.

Comment: i know script is running as echo works ok. i have also chown command which works ok. it is just cp command that wont work. it doesnt generate any error or anything. so i dont know what to do to make it work

Comment: If there is no error message, then how do you know it does not work?

Comment: it doesnt copy the files. if typed from terminal it does

Comment: Probably is a permission in the folder that you are copying the file to

Comment: I'm new to bash script, can I ask you guys that -rv and -rf, what do they do? and how effect command?

Answer (score 7):

We seem to have doubt as to how this script fails.  If there is no error message then this is a strange one.  I suggest:

1. On the command line (which works), do a `which cp`
2. Whatever the reply, then copy that and use it as the `cp` in the script (e.g. `/bin/cp`)
3. Check the widcard expansion, run your script with `bash -x script-name` and see if you get what you expect.
4. `echo $?` after the copy in the script - if it is zero then it (thinks it) worked.
5. Do a `ls -ld /var/www/ksite/app` from your script, maybe someone set a symbolic link?
6. If it still fails, source the script from the command-line and see if that works `. script-name`
7. Double check that the copy did actually fail!  (maybe that should be step 1.)

Comment: i tried with bash -x script-name and it worked, so i concluded that script works if called from terminal. Previously i was testing the script called from php file using '$output = shell_exec('bash /var/www/test/b.sh'); echo $output';  Why it is failing when used from php?

Comment: File permissions? Presumably PHP is running as a different user.

Comment: /bin/bash, /bin/cp and my .sh script are all set to 0755, so anyone can run these

Comment: AH HA!  `bash -x script-name` worked you say?   Maybe your `#!` line is wrong, see @unwind's answer above.  Maybe your bash script is not running from PHP?  PHP programs sometimes run in a weird environment (for security), are you picking up a restricted shell?  By the way, it might have helped if you had mentioned PHP from the outset.

Comment: i found the problem.

missing permission on the destination folder. so cp coundnt create files/folders and failed to execute.
from terminal everything was ok as that user had permissions to create files in destination folder.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you really have bash at `/bin/bash`. I think a batter hash bang is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

This uses the [env](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) command to locate the bash binary and set the environment.

Comment: please see my comment above. script works ok. it is just cp command that doesn't anything (not copying files/folders and not showing any errors). The strange bit is that if i run the same in the terminal it works ok. I used absolute path intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. What helped me:

1. I used windows and putty to write script, so I had \r\n at the end of lines. Be sure, you have only \n symbol.
2. I copied files and the only way it worked for me at script was `cp <source_dir>/fileName <dest_dir>/fileName` whereas at command line `cp <source_dir>/fileName <dest_dir>` worked well too.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue to Vladmir where the script was created in Windows.  I created a new file "my_bash_script.sh" in the linux environment using VIM, then read the contents of my script into the file:

:r file_made_in_windows.sh

Then I saved, closed, then set the file as executable:

chmod 744 my_bash_script.sh

From there, I ran the script:

./my_bash_script.sh

...and it worked.  What a weird issue.  I was confounded for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just covering all the bases .. do the permissions vary between the excutions .. i.e. do you execute one with sudo/root privileges, the other as user (unlikely, but thought I'd ask since we don't know what the exact error is)

Comment: @Kupe3 I brought up the permission issue 2 hours ago in a comment :)